# Form PHP working on one domain and not the other

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, dns

I developed my clients website on my test domain and got it working perfectly (with a little help from the stackoverflow crew). But, as soon as I transfered it to my clients domain (which is on the same webspace as my test domain I might add) the form stopped working.

Here is my test domain with the site on it: http://nathanlangley.co.uk/main_site_6/index.html

And here it is on the clients URL: http://danjamesconstruction.com/

The Javascript that calls the process.php is within the HTML.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'm afraid we will not be able to help you since your question is too short and lacks detail. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access `process.php` on the test server, it outputs the wanted data. However, if you do it on the other one - well, you get the files contents instead.

You might want to look and verify that php is turned on for the `danjamesconstruction.com`-domain (ie its directories).

Comment: Are you sure? It still prompts the download on my end - this with another browser to ensure that it wasn't caching it or something.

Comment: Yes. I don't think it takes time from the hosting providers point of view to tick over though. I'm going to have to look through my linking structure, but I'm sure it doesn't have anything to do with this as I've tripled check this before I pushed it live. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: I've submitted a ticket with them too, just in case I have missed something there.

Comment: Ok, now it's working, maybe it did need a few minutes to change.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you don't use event.preventDefault() in your #submit click handler. This will mean that in addition to the ajax request you could be having the form submit occur. Other than adding preventDefault() I don't see any issues with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://nathanlangley.co.uk/main_site_6/process.php)

Above link executes well since php is working fine .

Then try the following [link](http://danjamesconstruction.com/process.php)

You can see that its downloading the process.php not executing. This means PHP is not working on this server or configured incorrectly . Make sure the server is capable of executing php scripts .

Comment: http://danjamesconstruction.com/   Now i can see the program working, i got 'Thank you!
We have received your message.' message after submission . Then what do you mean by , not working . May be you are not receiving email. Check your spam folder if the code is sending email . Make sure the mailing code do the correct task .